# Copy the first characters to the line below if a condition is met

Tags: python-3.x

I´m new at python and I can´t really write  some code to help with the question. I don´t know if you can help me without a code. I will write my Input and desire output with a TXT file.

Input

```
03000|SOME_TEXT_1|XX|XXXX|21236,85
03100|29|21236,85
03000|SOME_TEXT_2|XX|XXXX|4270,00
03100|29|4270,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_3|XX|XXXX|17425,00
03100|29|17425,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|10600,00
03100|29|1040,00
03100|30|9560,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_5|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03100|29|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_6|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_7|XX|XXXX|11569,00
11111|12
```

Output

```
03000|SOME_TEXT_1|XX|XXXX|21236,85
03000|SOME_TEXT_1|XX|XXXX|03100|29|21236,85
03000|SOME_TEXT_2|XX|XXXX|4270,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_2|XX|XXXX|03100|29|4270,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_3|XX|XXXX|17425,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_3|XX|XXXX|03100|29|17425,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|10600,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|03100|29|1040,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|03100|30|9560,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_5|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_5|XX|XXXX|03100|29|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_6|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_7|XX|XXXX|11569,00
11111|12
```

Basically, I wanna to copy the first 26 characters from the line that starts with 03000 to the line below if the line starts with 03100, sometimes the line below can starts 11111 or another 03000, so I don´t wanna the text to be copied to those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
data = """03000|SOME_TEXT_1|XX|XXXX|21236,85
03100|29|21236,85
03000|SOME_TEXT_2|XX|XXXX|4270,00
03100|29|4270,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_3|XX|XXXX|17425,00
03100|29|17425,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|10600,00
03100|29|1040,00
03100|30|9560,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_5|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03100|29|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_6|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_7|XX|XXXX|11569,00
11111|12""".splitlines()

_03000_text = ''
output = []
for line in data:
    if not line.startswith("03"):
        output.append(line)
        continue

    if line.startswith("03000"):
        _03000_text = "|".join(line.split("|")[:-1])
        output.append(line)
        continue

    line = _03000_text + "|" + line
    output.append(line)

output = "\n".join(output)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
03000|SOME_TEXT_1|XX|XXXX|21236,85
03000|SOME_TEXT_1|XX|XXXX|03100|29|21236,85
03000|SOME_TEXT_2|XX|XXXX|4270,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_2|XX|XXXX|03100|29|4270,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_3|XX|XXXX|17425,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_3|XX|XXXX|03100|29|17425,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|10600,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|03100|29|1040,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_4|XX|XXXX|03100|30|9560,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_5|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_5|XX|XXXX|03100|29|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_6|XX|XXXX|11569,00
03000|SOME_TEXT_7|XX|XXXX|11569,00
11111|12
```

---

For multiple files, this should do what you want:

```
file_list = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]

for file in file_list:
    new_file = ".".join(file.split(".")[:-1]) + "_new.txt"

    with open(file) as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()

    _03000_text = ''
    output = []
    for line in data:
        if not line.startswith("03"):
            output.append(line)
            continue

        if line.startswith("03000"):
            _03000_text = "|".join(line.split("|")[:-1])
            output.append(line)
            continue

        line = _03000_text + "|" + line
        output.append(line)

    output = "\n".join(output)


    with open(new_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(output)
```

Note that it puts the output in separate files

Comment: Thanks! It does the job for me.

Comment: can you help me make this code works with multiples txt?